# assigning to list.extend to variable in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, methods, extend

I just started out learning python and am playing around with list methods. I bumped into this problem; assigning list.extend to a variable doesn't work the way I thought it would and I'm not sure why.

```
alph = ["a", "b", "c"]
num = [0, 1, 2,]

num_alph = alph.extend(num)
print num_alph
```

Printing num_alph results in none but I was expecting it print this;
["a", "b", "c", 0, 1, 2]

Rewriting the code to this gets me the expected result:

```
alph = ["a", "b", "c"]
num = [0, 1, 2,]

alph.extend(num)
num_alph = alph
print num_alph
```

Why does my former code print none instead of the extended list?

Comment: Because `list.extend()` returns `None`; all methods that alter the object in-place do so.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

[`.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) alters the content of the list in-place. It doesn't create a new one with the appended elements to it so doesn't make sense returning the same list. If you want `alph` to remain unchanged after extend, you should create a new list:

```
>>> num_alph = alph + num
>>> print num_alph
['a', 'b', 'c', 0, 1, 2]
```

--

```
>>> alph.extend(num)
>>> print alph
['a', 'b', 'c', 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: It is like `.sort()`.